# Bootstrap navbar offpage links not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap and am trying to learn it using the excellent W3schools website. I am basing my page on http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp.  I have tried changing the hrefs in the navbar to offpage links but nothing works. I click the menu and nothing happens.  Onpage links work fine. 
How do i do offpage links?
TIA
Sample code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Home<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts">example</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the snippet of the navbar code in question.

My guess are you are not adding http to the href of the navbar. Try something like the on below:

```
<a href='http://example.com'>example</a>
```

Comment: Please see above.  Sorry for not indenting the code.